# Angular 9 application build fails when working with linked libraries

Tags: angular, angular-ivy, npm-link

I am developing an application and a bunch of libraries to be used in the application. All are recently upgraded to Angular 9. The libraries are configured to build without ivy and the application is configured to build with ivy, which is as per the upgrade guidelines. The local development process I used to follow is as below -

1. Build the library and application with --watch.
2. Make changes in the library. After library build succeeds, copy dist/my-lib and paste it in the application's node_modules folder(this triggers the application build).

This worked till Angular 8 and below but with Angular 9 the application build errors out saying:
**ERROR in Tried to overwrite path/node_modules/my-lib/lib/services/payment.service.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.**

So, now I have to additionally do the following -

1. Stop the application build.
2. Delete the lib from application's node_modules and then copy paste the new one.
3. Start the application again.

The angular docs says to use npm link https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#linked-libraries. But I am not able to get the meaning of :

> the library's package.json configuration points at the correct entry points. For example, main should point at a JavaScript file, not a TypeScript file.

I tried npm link but that doesn't trigger the application build and my changes are not reflected.
I would like to know how to resolve the npm link issue or if there is a better way to work with libs and apps together.

My lib's package.json looks like this (Since I am working on a client application, I am only posting the package.json structure):

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "description": "description",
  "repository": {
    "url": "http://private-nexus-url"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-ci": "npm run test-headless && npm run sonar && npm run publish",
    "test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox --code-coverage",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-lib": "ng build --prod my-lib",
    "publish": "npm run build-lib && cd dist/my-lib && npm publish",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.6",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.6",
    ...
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I normally roll my eyes when people say this, but in this instance it might actually help since there's possibly a file access permissions issue, have you tried wiping node_modules and running `npm i` again? Also, close all terminals or editors that are opened in that directory.

Comment: @RichardDunn What specifically do you roll your eyes at? That wasn't clear. I ask because the only way I've successfully linked (and watched changes) in a library in a 9/10 version is by turning ivy off in the consuming application.

Comment: I was rolling my eyes at my own suggestion, but after rereading the question I don't think I actually read it properly in the first place. I'd try setting symbolic links to your libs, it's similar to the flow you have now so results might be the same, but it's easy to try. Failing that, [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had absolutely the same problem.
Turns out, the `postinstall: ngcc` entry you have there is only needed with Angular version 9.0.0

I'm running 9.1.10, and removing the `postinstall: ngcc` entry fixed the issue for me.

Also, I opted for a library re-design, as we're integrating another build system. I really don't like linking libraries. Yes, you evade any checksum problems you might have when developing the library in parallel with your main application (if you include the library as a dependency in your package.json that is). My favorable long-term solution is to have a separated library which deliverable / artifact gets consumed by the application, has a package.json and a corresponding package-lock.json entry.

Answer (score 0):

that works for me

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/mylib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For use a local library to another agular projet you can do this :

1. after creating your library, you can build there whith : ng build yourLibrary
2. Go to the dist folder : ./dist/yourlibrary/
3. Link them whits npm : npm link
   npm link create a similik in npm local package
4. Go to the home of your application et link the library whits your application : npm link yourLibrary

After you do that, you can use the library in your project :
exemple :

> > in your app.module.ts
> > import the library like this :
> > import {yourLibraryModule} from 'yourLibrary';

Them use your library like another node module.
and start your application
It's OK for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tinquiet and apologies for the late reply. I tried this already but it didn't work. If I run my application and library builds simultaneously with --watch option, then changes in lib build doesn't trigger app rebuild.